# How to Show a Number in Gujarati Native Digits in Windows Forms Application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization

I want to Develop `Gujarati` `Windows form application` using `c#.net`. 
But i have problem that

1) Calculation of two number in Gujarati. I Solved by this code

```
public static double ParseValue(string value)
{
    return double.Parse(string.Join("",
        value.Select(c => "+-.".Contains(c)
           ? "" + c: "" + char.GetNumericValue(c)).ToArray()),
        NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
}
```

But this Code Provide Me in Eng Numeric Value.

But When Calculate two Guajarati no, i get output in english. Like This:

```
 Label1.Text = (ParseValue(TextBox1.Text) + ParseValue(TextBox2.Text)).ToString();

//Output is Like this
// ૩ + ૬ = 9
```

So How can i get output in Gujarati numeric No.

2) What is Data type for Gujarati Value in `Microsoft Access`?
For Numeric, DateTime ETC..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`NumberFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.numberformat?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of a [`CultureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) to find information about number format of a culture including:

- [NativeDigits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.nativedigits?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8): a string array of native digits equivalent to the Western digits 0 through 9.
- [NegativeSign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.negativesign?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8):  the string that denotes that the associated number is negative.
- [NumberDecimalSeparator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8): the string to use as the decimal separator in numeric values.

Then you can use this information to convert your number to native format.

For example:

```
public string GetNativeRepresentation(double value)
{
    var format = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("gu-IN").NumberFormat;
    return String.Join("", value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                 .Select(x =>
                 {
                     if ("1234567890".Contains(x.ToString()))
                         return format.NativeDigits[x - '0'];
                     else if (x == '-')
                         return format.NegativeSign;
                     else if (x == '.')
                         return format.NumberDecimalSeparator;
                     else
                         return x.ToString();
                 }));
}
```

For example:

```
MessageBox.Show(GetNativeRepresentation(-1234567890.123));
```

Shows:

```
-૧૨૩૪૫૬૭૮૯૦.૧૨૩
```

It's better to store each type independent from culture, for example, use standard language types like `int`, `double` and `DateTime`, Then in the application using .Net Framework localization mechanisms, show localized version of values.

Comment: thanks, but it's work only int positive value but when we get negative and decimal value then how can work with this type of value.

Comment: thanks sir, it's possible to convert "PRIYANK" in English and Show in Gujarati like 'પ્રિયંક' .

Comment: Your last comments is about translation and I have no idea about translation. You may want to use some translation service like google translate or bing translator.

Comment: Sir which type of  data type use for numeric in gujarati,date time in Gujarati , string values in gujarati in ms access?

Comment: I think it's better to store each type independent from culture, for example, use int, double and datetime. Then in the application using .Net Framework localization mechanisms, show localized version of your values.